# SVN commit new/updated revision of previously imported, non-versioned files

Tags: svn, version-control

I have a directory on a server that I added to svn via svn import.  I have made edits to the files and would like to check them in to that path, but locally, there is no version control, this is not a working copy.  I know I could remove the directory, then check it out from SVN to its previous location, make the changes, then check in, but is there a way to accomplish this without doing that, possibly by using import to create a version history of the same local directory?  This is more of a curiosity, since I realize I am swimming against the current here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a working copy. There is really no way around that. However, you should be able to avoid deleting & checking out again by using the second technique outlined in [this Subversion FAQ entry](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#in-place-import)

You've already performed the `svn import`, so now you just need to do the `svn checkout --force <URL> <LOCALPATH>`.